# How to exclude many directories of node_modules from parsing for gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-modules

I have on my project a modular structure, where in each module there is a directory node_modules. I want to use gulp for automation. Many tasks require parsing directories and I want to exclude node_modules from the available ones. For example, I have the following structures:

```
node_modules
someFolder / node_modules
xFolder / yFolder / node_modules
aFolder / bFolder / dFolder / node_modules
```

If I want to exclude node modules for the top level then I specify
 `"!node_modules/**/*"` But how can I exclude nested directories of node_modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with gulp for automation, but it looks like it allows the globbing syntax.  Have you tried something like `"!**/node_modules/**/*"` ?

Comment: It fix my issue. Thank you!